# how can I verify content based on future date?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-jvm

I have a content to verify in a webpage which will change after a month or so? how can I write code for this with java in selenium that if today's date is 25th dec then verify some content. I dont want to change todays date from calendar date picker. By default when current date reaches to certain time ( for exmp 25th dec) then it will verify those content or else verify current content.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime to dynamically change dates based off of your current date to get consistent results.

For instance, if you want yesterdays date in the MM/dd/yyyy format, you can call the following:

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Or if you want tomorrows date:

```
DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want a specific line of code (or block/function etc), to run on a specific date. Although I do not recommend the following solution (it might add more complexity to your code and make it hard to understand etc), this should work for you:

```
DateTime desiredDate = new DateTime(2017, 12, 25, 00, 00, 00)
if(DateTime.Now.isAfter(desiredDate)
{
    //TODO stuff on 25th December 2017
}
```

So every time your code runs, it will check if the moment running is after your desired date. If so, your code inside the if statement will run.

The code above is from [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library, so you will have to include it in your project.